# If $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed, then they are same almost everywhere?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-verification

Is it true that if $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed, then they are equal almost everywehre? I am wondering whether this is true, and came up with the following argument.

Since they are identically distributed, by change of measure we have

$$\mathbb{E}\left[X\right] = \int_\Omega X \,d\mathbb{P} = \int_\mathbb{R} x\,d\mu = \int_\mathbb{R} y\,d\mu = \int_\Omega Y \,d\mathbb{P} = \mathbb{E}\left[Y\right]$$

Since $X$ and $Y$ have the same expectation, they are same almost everywhere.

Is my proof correct? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "almost everywhere"? If you mean that the random variables are equal almost surely (which seems to be the most natural definition), then no, this is false -- but perhaps you mean that their *density functions* are equal almost everywhere, or something like that?

Comment: @AaronMontgomery No, I mean $\mathbb{P}\left( X \ne Y\right) = 0$.

Comment: Two fair and independent six-sided dices A and B have the same distribution. The average value (expectation) of A and the average value of B are both  3.5. But, if you throw the two dices, they do not always give the same value. Continuous random variable X is like a dice with infinite sides. The chance that the value of X and the value of Y are equal is infinitesimally small, which is 0. $P(x \ne y) = 1$

Comment: Moreover, even if two distributions have the same expectation, the two distributions can be different. For example, distributions W and V can have the same average but different variance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Just cause RVs have the same expectation doesn't mean they are equal almost surely (which I assume is the sense in which you use 'almost everywhere'). That's an even weaker property than being identically distributed. In fact, if they are identically distributed, they are not necessarily equal almost surely.

An example would be if $X$ and $Y$ are independent RVs with the same distribution. In a lot of cases (say, for a continuous distribution) the probability that $X=Y$ is zero.

Comment: I couldn't find where I got it wrong. Essentially I'm using the fact that if $\int_\Omega Z \,d\mathbb{P} = 0$ then $Z = 0$ almost everywhere. In this case my $Z$ is just $X-Y$?

Comment: $\int_\Omega Z dP = 0$ does not imply $Z=0$ almost everywhere. It would if $Z$ were non-negative, but that's clearly not the case here.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused... Suppose both $X$ and $Y$ are non-negative. Are you saying that if they are identically distributed, it is true that $E(X) = E(Y)$. This implies that $E(X - Y) = 0$. But it is not clear at all that $X-Y$ is non-negative, so we cannot conclude $X = Y$ a.s. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. (I wasn't assuming $X$ and $Y$ nonenegative since that wasn't an assumption you made in your question, but it doesn't matter whether they are or not.)

Comment: I was thinking about two Chi-square distribution and plot of their density function. Since their plot overlap, somehow I thought that we always have $X(\omega) = Y(\omega)$. But I guess that's miss leading because the plot is about $P(X < t)$, but doesn't tell me what $X(\omega)$ is. In fact I don't even know what $\Omega$ looks like and how $X$ assigns values...

Comment: Yeah, it seems you are having a hard time with the intuition here. I wouldn't worry too much right now with the $\omega$ and $\Omega,$ and just think of $X$ and $Y$ intuitively as random numbers. When $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed, it just means they have the same distribution. In other words their statistical properties are identical. If you repeated the draw of $X$ many times and the draw of $Y$ many times, the histograms would look the same. This doesn't mean $X$ and $Y$ are the same number. If they are $N(0,1)$ it wouldn't be at all surprising to get $X=-0.1$ and $Y=0.6.$

Answer (score 1):

No.

I liked (and upvoted) spaceisdarkgreen's answer, but for another perspective, consider jointly-defined random variables $X, Y$ whose joint density is $1$ on $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$. Then both $X$ and $Y$ are uniform variables on $[0, 1]$, but $\mathbb P(X = Y) = 0$ -- in particular, they're independent.

To address where the specific flaw in your proof is: you're right that identically-distributed variables have the same *expectation*, but that doesn't give you warrant to claim that the variables are equal to one another. Consider $X$ which is $\pm 1$ (each with probability $1/2$) and $Y$ which is $\pm 2$ (each with probability $1/2$). The expected value of both $X$ and $Y$ are $0$, and yet they are equal to one another with probability $0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Example:** If $X$ has the standard normal distribution and $Y:=-X$, then $Y$ has the same distribution as $X$ (by symmetry) but the event $\{X=Y\} = \{X=-X\}=\{X=0\}$ has probability $0$.